# C# Bitmap screenshot size

Tags: c#, bitmap, byte, screenshot

I'm trying to get how the size (in bytes, not in Width x Height) is calculated. I made a checking application which takes screenshot of current desktop in 24bbp state each second, then write it to MemoryStream and to byte[] with ImageConverter, then compare sizes. Each screenshot is different in size, but shouldn't it be Width x Height x 3 or smth like that? Here's testing code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Check
{
    System.Timers.Timer t;
    ImageConverter converter;
    MemoryStream ms;
    byte[] arr;
    public Check()
    {
        converter = new ImageConverter();
        t = new System.Timers.Timer();
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Elapsed += T_Tick;
        t.Start();
    }

    private void T_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                               Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                               PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
        gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);

        ms = new MemoryStream();
        bmpScreenshot.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        arr = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmpScreenshot, typeof(byte[]));
        Console.WriteLine($"MS: {ms.Length}  --- byte[]: {arr.Length}");

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new Check();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

and here's the output

```
MS: 76638  --- byte[]: 94893
MS: 90487  --- byte[]: 107863
MS: 92424  --- byte[]: 109281
MS: 93692  --- byte[]: 110295
MS: 95222  --- byte[]: 111055
MS: 96586  --- byte[]: 112314
MS: 104584  --- byte[]: 117970
MS: 108438  --- byte[]: 120089
...and so on
```

So the size changes each frame it can begin to decrease eventually, but shouldn't that be static, or is there a way to achieve static size of images?

UDP: Changed format to bmp, here's another output:

```
MS: 3148854  --- byte[]: 104699
MS: 3148854  --- byte[]: 116002
MS: 3148854  --- byte[]: 121262
MS: 3148854  --- byte[]: 125048
```

so the MemoryStream is static now, but ImageConverter result is still changing.

Comment: Jpeg is a compressed format. If the screen content changes its compressed size is expected to change. - Also: _shouldn't it be Width x Height x 3_ Do you know about Stride?

Comment: Updated Q with bmp format, now results are different

Comment: Check() is correct or what do you mean?

Comment: Hm, interesting. Once I made sure the screen content doesn't chang (hide the output pane and stop my clock's seconds hand) the array size stays constant. Otherwise some small change keep happening. Probably some  (most likely lossless) compression, as the numbers  for ms suggest.

Comment: It compiles well, as it is Check class constructor, it doesn't matter for the app anyway and u can use void Check() if you aren't creating a separate class. This isnt a full app, just an app to check this.

Comment: Also for PNG ImageFormat, MemoryStream and ImageConverter produces the same byte length

Comment: _It compiles well, as it is Check class constructor_ Ah you're right, I pasted it directly without a class. Sorry. Interesting about PNG - so it looks as if ImageConverter actually produces a byte array for PNG. I hadn't come around testing this format, yet..Not really surprising as it is common and works so well.. - So I guess we have all the puzzle pieces in place..?

Comment: Ye seems so, but there's no information on MSDN about that conversion or in a commentary to ImageConverter class, which is strange. Now think it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting puzzle.

It consists of three questions:

- Why do the numbers change for the stream?
- Why do the numbers change for the byte array?
- Why do the numbers for stream and array differ?

Any compression result will depend on content; even slight changes, like a moving clock hand or an additional line in the the VS output pane will make some difference..

Let's add another result, this time for `Png` and with a constant screen content:

```
MS: 618997  --- byte[]: 618997
MS: 618997  --- byte[]: 618997
MS: 618997  --- byte[]: 618997
MS: 618997  --- byte[]: 618997
```

Now we can conclude:

- The stream numbers differ as long as we don't make sure that either the screen content won't change or we use a non-compressed format like `bmp`. We must hide the output pane, disable any clocks with a seond hand etc..
- The array numbers differ as long as the screen content changes
- The stream and array numbers are the same when we store as `png`.

From this we can conclude that `ImageConverter` stores images compressed as byte arrays in the `Png` format; this is nice as it saves memory. MSDN doesn't document it, though. (They probably don't want to guarantee this..)